# How to write a formal proof of the statement: if $x<3$ then $10-2x>4$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

**Prove:** *For all real numbers $x$, if $x<3$ then $10-2x>4$*.

*Proof:* Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $x<3$. We have the following sequence of implications:
$10-2x>4 \Rightarrow -2x>4 \Rightarrow x<3.$

Is my proof correct?

- Do I need to explain/show all algebra steps?
- How do I end this proof?

### Update:

In under 5 minutes I have learned the following from everyone's comments:

- I am proving a statement in the form $P \Rightarrow Q$. So I must derive Q from P, or I must show that I can reach Q by starting from P.
- Even though I have "proved" the statement in reverse, I can at least use my algebraic steps to my advantage so I can help build P to reach Q.

Comment: Your proof is not correct. You have to reverse all arrows, because you want to show that **if** $x < 3$, **then** $10 - 2x > 4$. What you show is that **if** $10 - 2x > 4$, **then** $x < 3$.

Comment: You have shown that if $10-2x > 4$, then $x < 3$. You need to start with $x < 3$ and perform algebra to show $10-2x > 4$. I can offer some advice: with these sorts of inequalities, it can be useful to perform the algebra to reduce $10-2x > 4$ (in this case) to $x < 3$ to see what operations you need to perform. Just make sure that every step you perform when doing this is valid in the other direction (that is, the one you need to prove).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have to prove that $x\lt 3\Rightarrow 10-2x\gt 4$.

We have
$$x\lt 3\Rightarrow 2x\lt 6\Rightarrow  -2x\color{red}{\gt} -6\Rightarrow 10-2x\gt 4.$$

Comment: Can't his proof be made correct by substituting the arrow signs with a $\iff$ sign?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is wrong. For one, arrows should be reversed.

If $x<3$, then $-2x>-6$, so $10-2x>4$.