# How to write a formal proof of the statement: For all real numbers $x$, if $x \ge 1$ then $\frac{3|x-2|}{x} \le4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

### *For all real numbers* $x$, *if* $x\ge1$ *then* $\frac{3|x-2|}{x} \le 4$

I understand that I must algebraically show how to build on $x\ge1$ to reach $\frac{3|x-2|}{x} \le4$, but cant for the life of me! I also tried to find a counter example but cant either. I would love any hints on how to go about proving this?

I have done a similar problem in the [past](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929883/how-to-write-a-formal-proof-of-the-statement-if-x3-then-10-2x4/929891#929891). I feel  there is something possibly silly am missing.

Comment: Start by rewriting $$\frac{\lvert x-2\rvert}{x} = \left\lvert 1 - \tfrac{2}{x}\right\rvert.$$ Then what can you say about $\frac{2}{x}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Good hint, hopefully he'll be able to finish the prob.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I am probably still not seeing it. But am trying; thanks for not giving me the answer right away :) I have one question: I thought I am supposed to reconstruct $x\ge1$ not decompose $\frac{3|x-2|}{x}\le4$ to reach $x\ge1$...

Comment: You _use_ $x\geqslant 1$ to reach the conclusion $\frac{3\lvert x-2\rvert}{x} \leqslant 4$. So $x\geqslant 1 \implies \text{ something about } \frac{2}{x}$, then use that to go further towards the goal. [But, to find a proof, one often starts at both ends and tries to meet in the middle, and only when writing up the proof everything flows neatly in one direction.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those tricky ones where it helps to start with what you want, then work backward until you get to a point that you know is true. For example, we know that $x \geq 1$ so we can do this:

$$6 \leq 7x \leq 8x+6 \\ \implies 6-4x \leq 3x \leq 4x+6 \\ \implies -4x \leq 3x-6 \leq 4x\\ \implies  -4x \leq 3(x-2) \leq 4x \\ \implies -4 \leq \frac{3(x-2)}{x} \leq 4 \\ \implies\left|\frac{3(x-2)}{x} \right| \leq 4 \\ \implies \left|\frac{3}{x} \right| \left|x-2 \right| \leq 4 \\ \implies \frac{3}{x} \left|x-2 \right| \leq 4$$